# Traces of infinite-dimensional matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, trace, infinite-matrices

Suppose $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space (dimension $N$ over the field $k$), and suppose $A$ is an $(N \times N)$-matrix over $k$ which defines a bijective linear transformation $f$ on $V$. (We assume the Axiom of Choice and work relative to a fixed base.)

My first naive question is: since $f$ has a unique inverse, does this mean that $A$ also has a unique inverse ?

Now for my real question.

Suppose $A, B, C$ are $(N \times N)$ $(0,1)$-matrices such that
$AB = CA$ (where we assume that the products are well defined), and such that $B$ and $C$ are permutation matrices. (Note that $N$ is still supposed to be infinite.)

When can we conclude that $\mathrm{trace}(B) \ne 0$ if and only if $\mathrm{trace}(C) \ne 0$ ?

Can even more be concluded about the traces of $B$ and $C$ (such as in the finite-dimensional case) ?

**EDIT**: in a first version, I assumed $A$ to be a permutation matrix instead of $B$ and $C$, and then the answer appears to be that $B$ and $C$ have the same trace. But when $A$ is not necessarily a permutation matrix while $B$ and $C$ are, in general this property does not seem to be true anymore ...

Comment: If $A$ is a permutation matrix then the sum defining trace($B$) and the sum defining trace($C$) are rearrangements of each other. So this seems to be a simple question about rearranging infinite sums, slightly disguised. Since you assume $B, C$ are $(0,1)$-matrices, there is no problem. More generally if the sum defining trace($B$) is absolutely convergent there is no problem (the sums are equal).

Comment: @SeanEberhard: could you describe your ideas in detail in an answer ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us (by editting your question and adding detail) what you've tried.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: I just noticed that I want $B$ and $C$ to be permutation matrices, but not necessarily $A$. In case that $A$ is a permutation matrix, the transpose of $A$ is its unique inverse, and it follows quickly that $B$ and $C$ have the same trace. But in the other case ...